# GDAL Rasterize over attribute (rewriting raster issue) in QGIS

Tags: gdal, qgis-python-console, gdal-rasterize

I'm trying to process gdal:rasterize_over in QGIS Python console. The same problem persists - this function is rewriting the input sample raster instead of making a new one as output. I've tried (look below) to specify the name of output raster in the same folder, but to no avail:

```
processing.run("gdal:rasterize_over",
{'INPUT':'C:/Users/user/vector_sample.gpkg|layername=water_bodies',
'INPUT_RASTER':'C:/Users/user/raster_sample.tif', 
'FIELD':'band',
'ADD':False,',
OUTPUT':'C:/Users/user/raster_rewrited.tif',
'EXTRA':'-at'})
```

What could you recommend me to modify? It looks like it should work perfectly, according to description of "gdal:rasterize_over" after prompting to parameters of gdal:rasterize_over in help menu.

Comment: Could you please finish the sentence: "according to..."? . Thanks.

Comment: Is your issue that the tool doesn't overwrite/replace the raster itself, but instead it overwrites the values in the existing raster?

Comment: It should create a new raster, but it overwrites the values in existing raster. P.S. Finished the end of sentence.

Comment: Possibly the documentation could be improved but no, it shouldn't create a new raster. That's why it has an input raster parameter, not an output raster parameter.  If you want to create a new raster, use [`gdal:rasterize`](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/vectorconversion.html#gdalrasterize)

Comment: If your aim is to use an existing image as a template, update some pixels, save the result into a new file, and keep the both versions, then maybe your question is a duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/416616/feed-an-existing-raster-to-qgis-raster-destination-parameter-in-qgis-processing.

Comment: Yeah, gdal:rasterize will only work in this case (which is the shame because it complicate my workflow with an extra step).